# .htaccess - redirect invalid URL

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the following URL :
  `www.domain.com.au/--xyz-75/`

please suggest how do I redirect this url to homepage, i.e to `www.domain.com.au` using .htacees.

The .htaccess file in public_html folder.

Application is developed in php.

If it is not possible in .htaccess , then is there any other way?

Answer (score 1):

In conjuction with the other answers, the rewrite engine must be turned on in order this soltuion to work,

```
RewriteEngine on
Redirect /--xyz-75/index.php http://www.domain.com.au/
```

Another way is to use simple HTML code in index.html (or index.php) file inside your `www.domain.com.au/--xyz-75/` folder:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1;URL=http://www.domain.com.au/" />
```

Answer (score 1):

have you tried adding this line of code in your .htaccess file:

```
Redirect 301 /--xyz-75/ /
```

this will simply redirect from your url to root which is "www.domain.com.au" in your example.

Answer (score 0):

In `.htaccess`:

```
Redirect /--xyz-75/index.php http://www.domain.com.au/
```

In your PHP file you have many options to do that. With PHP header location:

```
<?php header("Location: http://www.domain.com.au/"); ?>
```

With JS, problem is that it will work only if JS is enabled in user's browser:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.location = "http://www.domain.com.au/"
</script>
```

And with HTML:

```
<meta http-equiv="REFRESH" content="0;url=http://www.domain.com.au/">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this in .htacces

```
RewriteEngine on    
Redirect /--xyz-75/ http://www.domain.com.au/
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution :

```
RewriteEngine On 
#if requested filename is not a existing file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
#if requested filename is not a existing directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
#Rewrite the url
RewriteRule ^--([^/]+)/?$ http://example.com [R,L]
```

This redirects :

```
example.com/--foo
```

to

```
example.com
```